# How can I change a die line color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, line-art, cutter

I have a flat die line image in `jpg` format ready to go to the machine for cutting, but the machine accepts only a red pattern to cut through and the current image has a pattern in blue.

I have tried manually changing the color in Photoshop but there are some curves and edges that I could not color correctly.

How do I change the blue to red in Photoshop? I am using CS6

[image: the blue pattern that needs to be red]

The machine accepts below red color (though with a white background instead of red):

[image: sample die lines]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to change those line colors to red with Photoshop is to just place a solid red layer on top and set the blending mode to **Color**.

[image: Photoshop screenshot]

My concern is that this file is very low quality and has lots of hidden [compression artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIFUa.png). My ultimate suggestion would be to vectorize the image (can be done in Photoshop but I used Illustrator). It is composed of very simple shapes so vectorization would be trivial.

[image: Illustrator screenshot]

This would make it easy to quickly change the die lines to whatever color you needed as well as produce a much higher quality output.